# Mostrar ID de carpeta/archivos y sus permisos

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

He tratado de mostrar los permisos de una carpeta y sus archivos pero no logro hacerlo funcionar , me tira un error de NULL.

Quiero lograr que en el log me muestre el id y después lance los permisos para

- la carpeta principal
- los archivos contenidos

este es el código

```
function showpermisssions() {

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1tLv4ZkSltTGpK34PcNJ-OQL5UAL67HWo");
  var files = folder.getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()) {

      // Print list of files inside the folder
      file = files.next().getId();
      var id = DriveApp.getFileById(file);
      try {
      
      var access     = file.getSharingAccess();
      var permission = file.getSharingPermission();
      var viewers    = file.getViewers();      
      var editors    = file.getEditors();
=
    }
catch (e) {Logger.log(id); Logger.log(access);Logger.log(permission);};

    // Recursive call for any sub-folders
 
  }
}
```

Comment: Cuando se solicita ayuda con un código que arroja error debería incluirse el mensaje de error textual y los detalles necesarios como indicar a qué línea se refiere el error. P.S. En este caso el código tiene unos problemillas obvios para quienes están familiarizados con Class File de Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando las asignaciones que usan la variable file para acceder a métodos de de Class File como `file.getSharingAccess()` están invertidos la asignación de valores/objetos en las siguientes líneas

```js
file = files.next().getId();
var id = DriveApp.getFileById(file);
```

debería ser

```js
id = files.next().getId();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
```

además hay un `=` fuera de lugar.